# SVG not rendering in Safari

Tags: svg

I have several pages on my site that show SVG images on any browser without a problem.  One of the pages shows two different SVG images, and one of them is a pretty complex image.  In my Chrome Web Browser, the complex image shows up without a problem, but when I try to view that page in Safari the SVG shows up with blank spots in the image where there is supposed to be content.

I think I need to replace the image with a PNG version of the SVG image for Safari browswers, but I have no idea how to do that.  Does anyone know how I can fix this SVG problem or replace the SVG with a PNG if the web client is safari?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do an inline SVG I dont think it's supported in Safari:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="newYear" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle id="year" cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="blue" />
        </svg>
    </body> </html>
```

You should try declaring it like you would an image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed src="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
        <object data="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
        <iframe src="circle.svg"></iframe>
    </body> </html>
```

I would also look into a PNG fallback.  A Google search will render results on how to do a fallback for legacy browsers.  Have you looked into previous question?

- [Not able to render SVG image in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012573/not-able-to-render-svg-image-in-safari)
- [Safari embeded SVG doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372695/safari-embeded-svg-doctype)

If you want a better answer I would suggest editing your question to show what you've tried and the code because it's hard to ask for help when we have no clue what the you're doing exactly.